# How to transition from a statement based log to row based log for Galera replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, galera

I'm new to clustering and I'm trying to implement a Galera cluster. I'm transitioning from a standalone MySQL instance to a MariaDB Galera Cluster consisting of (at the moment) 2 nodes.

I have installed MariaDB-Galera-server.x86_64 10.0.13-1.el6 & MariaDB-client.x86_64 10.0.14-1.el6 on a CentOS 6 server.

I have also converted all the MyISAM tables to InnoDB.

My question is how do I make the switch? I was reading the (old?) codership notes on how to set up the my.cnf (https://web.archive.org/web/20131021065420/http://www.codership.com/wiki/doku.php?id=mysql_galera_configuration) and they say that these parameters are Required:

```
binlog_format=ROW
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
```

My current log file (even though it's a standalone instance and not a cluster) is statement based and my database has a lot of data. How does making this change affect my current logs and current data?

Should I just make changes as per the my.cnf listed in the codership example file and play around until I get it right? Any other advice before I get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a one-node cluster, add those settings to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
```

Login in a run

```
mysql> reset master;
mysql> set global innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;
```

Shutdown mysql

```
service mysql stop
```

Go to the folder where the binary logs are located and manually delete the binary logs (should only be one at this point) and also the binary log index file.

Start up MySQL

```
service mysql start
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Rolando, the two nodes in the cluster are synced. I had to do some additional things to get it working and I need to do a lot of testing before I can deploy on production but at the very least, the replication part is working.

I had to add this extra line to my my.cnf:
 innodb_data_file_path   = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend

Comment: Is this answer specific to Galera, or is it applicable to any kind of replication? Does the slave need to be reconfigured in any way? The [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/binary-log-formats/#changing-the-binary-log-format) seems to suggest that the slave will fail if it's configured to use `STATEMENT` replication but the master's events come in as `ROW`, but I *think* that is for versions older than 10.0.22.

Comment: It's been a few years, now, so I figured I'd check: is it still necessary to delete the old binary logs before re-starting the MySQL instance? Is there a difference between MySQL and MariaDB in this regard?

Comment: Is it at all possible to ensure that any replicas have definitely fetched the latest writes to the binary log before stopping the primary server? Deleting those binary logs on the primary may end up losing data on the replicas if one isn't careful. Is the only option to stop all clients first (to ensure no new writes), then check the primary's binlog position, verify on the replicas, and *then* restart the primary (including possible deleting the binary logs)?